# I Use Two Forms with one Submit Button but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Using Two Forms with one Submit Button But Not Working.

1st Form of `__ Name , Email , Address __` is For Blogger Platform Which Works Fine Only when Published without Radio Buttons coding putting inside the Code.

2ns Form is Multiple Radio Options which works fine only when it is separated
from the other form.

Again I Want to remind you:

These Forms are for Blogger Website Platform which coded Well With fine working only in Separated form but when I combined the two forms with one 'Submit Now' button it Stop Working

Please Solve this Coding without affecting or removing any `id=""` attribute.
If I remove this code `id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit"` then the 1st Form Stops Working in Blogger Theme.

Is it possible to make One button working for two Forms?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
    if (event.target.type === "radio" && event.target.name === "number")
    {
        submitBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
});
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

```css
.widget.ContactForm {
    z-index: 1
}

.contact-form-widget {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:98%;
    padding: 25px 0;
    border:1px solid #b2b2b2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2%;
    -moz-border-radius: 2%;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.contact-form-widget .form {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.ribbon {
    font: 20px Arial;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position:center;
    background: #6B5F53;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding:7px 0 7px 0;
    margin:0 0 3px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.contactf-name,
.contactf-email,
.contactf-message {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:600
   
}

.contactf-name,
.contactf-email {
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}

.contact-form-name,
.contact-form-email,
.contact-form-email-message,
.contact-form-name:hover,
.contact-form-name:focus,
.contact-form-email:hover,
.contact-form-email:focus,
.contact-form-email-message:hover,
.contact-form-email-message:focus {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #aaa;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    border-top:1px solid #666666;
    border-left:1px solid #666666;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.contact-form-name,
.contact-form-email {
    height: 35px
}

.contact-form-email-message {
    height: 100px
}
.contact-form-button-submit,
.contact-form-button-submit:hover {
    margin-top: 25px;
padding:0 35px 0 35px;
    height: 37px;
    font: bold 18px Arial;
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333333;
    background: #d2d2d2;
}
.contact-form-button-submit:active {
    color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #d6a437;
    background: #febd4b;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#febd4b) to(#fed970));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970);
    background: linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#febd4b, #fed970)
}

.contact-form-cross {
    border: medium none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 11px !important;
    width: 11px !important;
}
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -O-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    opacity:1;
}

#header .bottom-header.blog h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
 color: red
}

input[type=radio]:hover + label {
border: solid 1px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
border: solid 2px white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 1px;
border-color : red;
color : red;
opacity:1;
}

input[type=text] {
font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text]:hover {
}
input[type=email]:hover {
}
```

```html
<div class="widget ContactForm" id="ContactForm22">
        <div class="ribbon"><strong>Your Billing Details</strong></div>
    <div class="contact-form-widget">
        <div class="form">
            <form name="contact-form">
                <div class="contactf-name">Your name <span style="color:red">*</span> :<input class="contact-form-name" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="Full Name" size="30" type="text" value="Full Name" onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Full Name";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Full Name") {this.value = "";}' /></div>
                <div class="contactf-email">E-mail address <span style="color:red">*</span> :<input class="contact-form-email" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="E-mail address" size="30" type="text" value="E-mail address" onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "E-mail address";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "E-mail address") {this.value = "";}' /></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div class="contactf-message">Your Address <span style="color:red">*</span> :<textarea class="contact-form-email-message" cols="25" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="Hometown/ City/ Your State...." rows="5" value="" placeholder="Hometown/ City/ Your State...." value="Hometown/ City/ Your State...." onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Hometown/ City/ Your State....";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Hometown/ City/ Your State....") {this.value = "";}'></textarea>
<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p>&nbsp;<label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.paypal.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Pay by Paypal</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.instamojo.com" name="number" id="number1"> Pay by InstaMojo</label></br>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.skrill.com" name="number" id="number2"> Pay by Skrill</label></br>
</p>
</form>
<input type="button" class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit" id="submitBtn" disabled onclick="window.open(getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']), '_blank');" value="Submit Now">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got a form nested in a form from the code you provided. Is there a reason to have two separate forms, or can they exist in one form? From what I can tell, there's not reason for two separate forms, just add your radios to the form you already got. When you have your devtools console open, are there any errors, because the snippet you provided throws errors when I select a radio option currently.

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have a form inside another form. You can only submit one form at a time.

Comment: I understand you may not know how to fix the code, but it would help us to help you if you could at least give us some help on what your final expectation is. I can't tell if you just want your JS code to run without error, or if indeed the form is supposed to get submitted somewhere (to a backend, etc).